# Center and vertical maximize window by clicking on it

Tags: 18.04, scripts, shortcut-keys, window

In Ubuntu 18.04 there is a shortcut to maximize vertically a window. What's missing is the functionality to center it at the same time. There are scripts out there to hack it but usually they are for a certain application.

I've seen xkill, where you click which window you want to be killed, would it be possible to have something equivalent where you have a shortcut that enables you to click on a window in order to center it and vertically maximize it?

Comment: Would this work? https://www.dropbox.com/s/cctlrj4d6er3m0n/vokoscreen-2019-02-16_17-27-11.mkv?dl=0

Comment: Drawing tiles might me counter-productive for what I was asking. Beyond this, it seems quite neat for someone that wanted to split **all** their windows in a specific setting.